# MySQL: is root a special user?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

That may sound like a silly question, but let me explain - I wanted to log on to MySQL as user `root` from several other systems, so I created this:

```
mysql> create user root@`10.254.%.%` identified by 'w0ws1kr1t';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> grant all on *.* to root@`10.254.%.%`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

But when I log on from a system with eg IP 10.254.1.95, it fails with:

```
2020-07-28 08:05:32 17917 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'10.254.1.95' (using password: YES)
```

On the other hand, if I don't use `root` but `newarch`, it works. I couldn't find it in the docs - is `root` reserved for local logins only?

Comment: I think that MySQL uses the first host pattern matched to your IP. But the first one in `mysql.user` table is `'root'@'%'`, and server tries to log you in using this account with non-matched password problem. Use another user name simply.

Comment: @Akina You are probably right - root@% was defined with no password for some reason, I remember wondering about that. I will check when I have chance.